# Unable to replace values using Dict on DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am creating a dictionary `code_data` by loading a CSV file to a data frame and converting it with `to_dict` method. This is a fragment of my code:

```py
path = "E:\Knoema_Work_Dataset\hrfpfwd\MetaData\MetaData_num_person.csv"
code_data = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=['value', 'display_value'], dtype=object)
code_data = code_data.set_index('value')['display_value'].to_dict()
```

In the following line I am attempting to replace its values:

```
data["Number of Deaths"] = data["Number of Deaths"].replace(code_data)
```

Sadly, it leads to an error:

```
Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'
```

Could you provide me with some assistance with regards to my problem?

Comment: Where do you create or define `Data`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.